# Data loss when passing a hash table into a function

Tags: c, function, hash

I created a hash table:

```
typedef struct _linked_list_{
    struct _linked_list_ *next;
    char *disk_name;
    struct disk *disk_object;
} linked_list;


typedef struct _hash_table_ {
    int size;
    linked_list **table;
} hash_table;
```

Where each entry of the hash table is a linked list. Then, in main I create an instance of a structure which has a structure variable that is a hash table:

```
int main() {
    health_monitor *starbucks;
    starbucks = malloc(sizeof(health_monitor));
    starbucks->id = "92838382";

    // THIS IS THE HASH TABLE!
    starbucks->disks_in_system = malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
    starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    starbucks->disks_in_system->size = 5;

    //initializing the first 5 rows to be NULL

    starbucks->disks_in_system->table[0] = NULL;
    starbucks->disks_in_system->table[1] = NULL;
    starbucks->disks_in_system->table[2] = NULL;
    starbucks->disks_in_system->table[3] = NULL;
    starbucks->disks_in_system->table[4] = NULL;

    //Making sure that the table rows were created correctly and contain NULL
    int counter;
    for(counter=0; counter <5; counter++){
        printf("The table row is: %s\n", starbucks->disks_in_system->table[counter]);
    }
    //passing the hash table into explore_current_directory function
    explore_current_directory(starbucks->disks_in_system, data_directory);       
    return 0;
}
```

The print statement inside the for loop that prints the table rows gives this output:

```
The table is: (null)
The table is: (null)
The table is: (null)
The table is: (null)
The table is: (null)
```

However, Once I pass the hash table into the function, only the first three rows seem to exist. Here is the function:

```
int explore_current_directory(hash_table* hm, char* directory){
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *ep;
    char* current_directory;
    dp = opendir(directory);

    int counter;
    for(counter=0; counter <5; counter++){
        printf("The table row is: %s\n", hm->table[counter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output from the print statement inside the for loop above:

```
The table row is: (null)
The table row is: (null)
The table row is: (null)
```

The last two rows seem like they do not exist.

I used to get a segmentation fault right after that, but I do not anymore (I do not know why.)

And the thing is that when I change the above function to this:

```
int explore_current_directory(hash_table* hm, char* directory){
    int counter;
    for(counter=0; counter <5; counter++){
        printf("The table row is: %s\n", hm->table[counter]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine.

Comment: what is `health_monitor`?

Comment: Health monitor is a structure. It has a structure variable disks_in_system, which is a hash table. The hash table is what I pass into the function that explores the directory.

Comment: `starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(sizeof(linked_list));`  -> `starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(sizeof(linked_list*));`

Comment: @Sourav - thank you, that's right! I fixed that, but the original program is not resolved.

Comment: malloc too small.  Suggest: `starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(sizeof(linked_list)); starbucks->disks_in_system->size = 5;` --> `starbucks->disks_in_system->size = 5; starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(starbucks->disks_in_system->size  *  sizeof *(starbucks->disks_in_system->table));`

Comment: Do not use `_` as a prefix for names. This syntax is reserved for standard language/library names.

Comment: Passing a non `char*` pointer to `printf()` as a value for a `%s` conversion specifier invokes undefined bahaviour.

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() and family of functions I.E. calloc() and realloc()

Comment: in function `explore_current_directory()` you forget to `closedir(dp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create five linked lists, but you're only `malloc`ing enough memory for one:

```
starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(sizeof(linked_list*));
```

Change that line to

```
starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(5 * sizeof(linked_list*));
```

Or, better, rearrange the initialization code as chux suggested in the comments to remove one of the magic numbers:

```
starbucks->disks_in_system->size = 5;
starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc ( starbucks->disks_in_system->size
                                           * sizeof(linked_list*) );
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `starbucks->disks_in_system->table = malloc(starbucks->disks_in_system->size* sizeof(linked_list *) );`, since we're allocating an array of pointers?